# Can't setup webhook

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I want to setup webhook to the server.
I am guided by this instruction (and several other): https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook/

Every time I get the same error: `Access denied for the scope urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.cT9kz1IxRZy5rgSCupQ3vg that you are trying to create hook on`

Please check the call:

```
curl -X 'POST'  -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/data/events/dm.version.added/hooks' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'authorization: Bearer '$1 -d '{
        "callbackUrl": "***",
        "scope": {
             "folder": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.cT9kz1IxRZy5rgSCupQ3vg"
        },
        "hookAttribute": {
          "projectId": "***"
        }

  }'
```

*** - was hidden.

Call structure is similar to example in documentation.
Folder exist. I will be glad receive any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I believe this can be one of 2 possible issues:

1. the 3-legged token you're using don't have access to this folder. Note the **Webhook** is created and stored per user per app, so the user (Autodesk Account that is logged in) need to have access to this folder.
2. the access token is missing the `data:read` `data:write` scopes required for webhooks.

Can you check this and share the results? Maybe add more details on your 3-legged and make sure the user can see the folder (e.g. list files on it with the access token).

Comment: Thank you very mach for your answer. I will check 3-legged token, but! 
How we can get token for standalone server? Is it possible to make webhook without web browser?

Comment: in this case the token needs to be 3-legged, authorized by user